# Authorization flow using AWS Cognito and Amazon verified permission service

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-cognito

I have spring boot application hosted in AWS. User requests will be routed to app endpoints wuth usage of AWS API Gateway. User Authentication implemented via AWS Cognito and in our case we need to configure RBAC and ABAC to endpoints of our application. We want to use Amazon Verified Permission service for authorization purposes. So, it can be helpful but I don't understand how to secure specific application endpoint, how it can be configured in `resource` section of AVP or may be this endpoint should be configure in `action` section? Maybe someone can help me with it and make it clear?